# Reviewing Triage questions leads to disputed flags

Tags: discussion, scope, triage, disputed-flags

This is specifically related to questions about coding problems. When reviewing a question without a single line of code provided, I mark this as 'Unsalvageable' -> Should be closed -> off-topic -> 'Why is this code not working'.
The reason why I do this is that almost all of these questions have the form:

> I want to [...some action here...] using [...some technology/language here...]. Please help

---

My problem: a lot of my flags are being disputed - apparently a coding problem/question is not off-topic on StackOverflow but on the other hand, not providing a minimal working code falls into the 'Why is this code not working' category (at least from my point of view).

How should I proceed in such cases? Is there any other flagging option which is more suitable for marking questions of the above mentioned form?