# Flagged post change caused my flag to be declined

Tags: discussion, flags, edits, declined-flags

Two days ago, I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31496989/1) as "not an answer".  Since then, it was edited twice into a good answer, which I believe was the reason for my flag being declined.

Two things:

- I see that too many declined flags leads to a [flagging rights suspension](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267870/too-many-declined-flags-to-flag-post).
- I also see that you cannot [unflag a post that has been edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251661/how-can-i-remove-a-flag-if-the-user-edited-and-improved-later).

What gives?  Doesn't this seem a little unfair?

Comment: Yes, but it's not a big deal.  If you do end up becoming banned due to a string of bad luck like this, I'm sure you can plead your case here on meta and a diamond mod might manually lift any unjust bans.

Comment: Are you sure that it was declined and not disputed? I thought an edit marked a flag as disputed

Comment: Oh and as for the original revision, it's in serious need of editing, but it does provide an answer.  So your flag might have been declined anyway.

Comment: Ah, that's another question I had but didn't actually want to put it in this post.  The original post had a question mark at the end, and I'd classify the whole "answer" as a suggestion at best.  Doesn't that mean it's more of a comment than an answer?  Where are guidelines on this that I could read to become a better reviewer and community member?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291974/3933332

Comment: if you were using canned [meta-tag:not-an-answer] flag (and not a custom one) then moderator could decline it only prior to edit, because currently [edits automatically dismiss such flags as helpful](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252854/165773)

Comment: @codeMagic I'm sure, the flag was declined

Comment: Triage reviews only questions, it doesn't work with answers. And it is known to [dispute](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299271/839601) flags, that's not the same as decline. The queue where you could flag an answer should be another one, maybe First Posts. But then again, edit is guaranteed to shake off NAA flags, so we better wait for moderator to tell us more. Frankly, it feels weird to decline flag on a post that looks like a comment, "Have you tried to replace your actual Angular Material version with 0.10.1-rc2 and play with z-index in your css like this #first_div{z-index:1000;} ?"

Comment: @gnat I did use the canned [not-an-answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/not-an-answer) flag, however this did not automatically mark my flag as helpful. The scenario was that I was reviewing questions in a review queue (forget which one), and flagged the question. Is it possible that the post that I saw in the review queue was modified before I flagged the original post?

Comment: ah! that's possible I think. And that could explain it. Even 2nd revision of the post could render your flag invalid from mod perspective (even though it still looked poor, but wasn't that much a comment anymore). I think moderator can clarify this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I declined that flag, and I think I see what happened here. I was operating under the same assumption that gnat posted above, in that [I thought that all edits automatically marked "not an answer" flags as helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252854/edits-shouldnt-dismiss-not-an-answer-flags). Therefore, I assumed your flag came after the edits and I saw nothing about the final answer that made it worth deleting, particularly since it was accepted by the asker.

However, your flag instead came right after [the initial version of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31496989/revisions) and before the two edits that fleshed it out. The edits did not clear your flag, as I had assumed they would, probably because these edits didn't come from review but were made by the poster themselves. Edits of that type don't appear to clear these flags, a case I was not aware of.

That said, I might have still declined the flag, even on the original version of the answer. While short and asking a question, it was still attempting to answer the question by providing a suggestion. I'm not sure that was worth deleting or converting to a comment.

Also, accepting a "not an answer" flag on something makes it eligible as a review audit case, and the audits are based on the current state of an answer. This would make that answer a really bad audit case, so accepting it even knowing the history probably wouldn't be something I'd do.

Sorry about the declined flag, but that's how I saw and acted on this.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  In the future, is it an ok idea to flag much more sparingly in only more clear-cut cases?  The consequence being that suggesting edits and comments on posts would be more prevalent.

Comment: @BradLarson "makes it eligible as a review audit case, and the audits are based on the current state of an answer": I think that this should not be a factor in your decision.

Comment: @BlasSoriano but that in conjunction with "I might have still declined the flag" and "I'm not sure that was worth deleting" should.

Comment: FYI, edits will clear Low Quality flags in all cases, but only edits from review will clear Not an Answer flags (bit of a historical anomaly there; the Low Quality clearing behavior predates the current review system).

Comment: It sounds like the real problem is the "bad flagger" limit is set too low, rather than the specific behind the scenes behavior of the system. One could even argue the system is too complex, requiring all this intricate knowledge on flag types and how they affect audits to use correctly.

Comment: @theMayer it is set as low to account for tremendous amount of flaggers (anyone with 15 rep can flag). If mods didn't have tools to quickly throttle mis-flagging, their brains would boil and eventually explode. And we would have to re-elect all 20 moderators likely 2-3 times a year

Comment: @Shog9: That is the most corner-casiest thing I have ever seen. Agh.

Comment: Yet another example of: We should be able to unflag posts. I've raised this before, it just makes no sense to leave a flag in place, wasting someone's time, when the flagger can see that it's no longer appropriate.